# consuming a WSDL-link as a WCF-service-refernce in C# VS2008

Tags: c#, wcf, request, assembly-references

I am trying to consume a WSDL-link say https://somewhere.com/somesetofservice?wsdl

This WSDL link, I am intendeding to consume the associated web-methods by adding it as a WCF-service-refernce in C# VS2008.  I am doing this inside a C#-class-library. Now everything goes fine... meaning :

[a] when I create an instance of clientProxy - it gets recognized.

[b] the clientProxy.somemethodname is available

[c] The 'somemethodnameresponse' (response of method) is also available

[d] BUT... 'somemethodnamerequest' (request of method) does NOT get recognized - gives compile time error.

The error message is "*The type or namespace name  could NOT be found - are you missing a using-directive or an assembly reference?"*

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It can be one or both of the following:

1. your C# class library does not reference the dll that contains 'somemethodnamerequest'
2. the C# file that reference 'somemethodnamerequest' does not have a using statement that references the namespace which contains 'somemethodnamerequest'

Comment: Thanks for getting Shiraz... but I have checked all that you have mentioned and they are correctly implemented.